# Is this a new feature of Chrome or what I did to turn this on?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

After upgrading my desktop Chrome to the latest version (`Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)`). There is a jigsaw icon on the toolbar.

It's very annoying to have such an icon in this crowded space. Is this a new feature of Chrome? Am I the only one who saw this?

Comment: Looks like a new feature, not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a new feature of Chrome?

It is indeed a new feature.  Of course, the feature was added with the release of Chrome 76, so I suppose it depends on your definition of a "new feature" is exactly.  *I suspect Google, with the release of Chrome 83, has simply changed what the default value is for `Extensions Toolbar Menu`*

> It's very annoying to have such an icon in this crowded space.

You can disable it by navigating to `chrome://flags/` and disabling `Extensions Toolbar Menu` afterwords you must relaunch Chrome.

Comment: @AGamePlayer I don't see it, FWIW. On Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Chrome  83.0.4103.97

Comment: @Ramhound The icon.

Comment: I only have 4 extensions, I wonder if it is an overflow icon displayed only if you have lots installed

Comment: @DavidPostill I just checked another google account, it has only 3 extensions but still shows this up.

Comment: I guess I must have removed it myself, I don't remember ...