# how to remove extensions settings icon from Chrome's extension bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

[image: Chrome Extensions icon in the upper right corner]

I would like to remove that icon of Extension settings (upper right corner) from the extensions bar. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a new feature of Chrome or what I did to turn this on?](https://superuser.com/questions/1563792/is-this-a-new-feature-of-chrome-or-what-i-did-to-turn-this-on)

Comment: @Ramhound no, this answer is all over internet and it does remove all extension icons - not what i want.

Comment: You didn’t ask how to remove all extension buttons.  You asked how to remove a specific button, one controlled by a flag, and the answer to the duplicate question explicitly explains how to disable that specific button. You will have to edit your question and be more specific about which button you want disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, my bad - i tried it again and it indeed worked... Happy to mark your answer if you make one.

Comment: This won't be answered because the question has been asked before and already answered there. This will be marked as a duplicate of the existing question so that others who find this will be directed to that.